# Form submit not displaying message

Tags: php, jquery

I have a HTML form with an ID of `newticket` and this JQuery in the head section of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#message").hide();
        $("#newticket").submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            dataString=$("#newticket").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "newticket_go.php",
                cache: false,
                data: dataString,
                success: function(res){
                    //$("#message").show();
                    $("#message").html(res);
                    $('#message').fadeIn('slow');
                    if(res.indexOf("success")!=-1)
                    {
                        window.location.href = res.substr(8);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have `<div id="message" class="messagebox"></div>` above the form to display the message once the form has been submitted.

My form looks like this:

```
<form action="newticket.php" method="post" id="newticket" name="form1">
```

The `newticket_go.php` file works fine as it runs the SQL query fine etc. there is some text echoing in `newticket_go.php` which should display in the message div but nothing is displaying.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the success callback is fired?

Comment: Or it could have failed?

Comment: You are using ajax to make the call to newticket_go.php, then why do you have action="newticket.php" defined in the form tag?  Seems to me newticket.php is going to be called first?

Comment: the form action does nothing as the JQuery does it all and i know its calling the newticket_go.php file as it runs the SQL Query that is there, there is no SQL Query in newticket.php

Comment: Can you please check the web inspector and inspect what is returned from the server. Also, are we sure that you're not setting `visibility:hidden` on the element?

Comment: here is newticket_go.php http://pastebin.com/RrNx7AkU as i said, the SQL is running fine

Comment: Sounds like you arent getting anything back. What happens when you console.log(res) in the callback?

Comment: mention `return false` at the end of your action

Comment: it works fine on another site though

Comment: Try to initialise variables that will be POSTed, and see if the php file echoes the data, that you are expecting.

Comment: i have put echo 'TEST TEXT'; at the top of the newticket_go.php file and that doesn't echo either

Comment: @charlie, your php code would be helpful here.  It could be that this line `window.location.href = res.substr(8);` is executing and you are not seeing the value.

Comment: @lowcase: the ajax code has `e.preventDefault()` to terminate the normal form submission.